# CollectionChanged event intercepted by POCO proxy

Tags: entity-framework, proxy, navigation, poco, observablecollection

I have a WPF ListBox with its ItemsSource bound to an ObservableCollection navigation property on an Entity Framework 4 POCO proxy. I want the user to be able to add and remove items to/from the list and then commit those changes by clicking on a [Save] button.

It mostly works, but the ListBox does not show added items until ObjectContext.CommitChanges() is called. It seems that the POCO proxy is intercepting the event for Action.Add operations and then, upon commit, reraising it or maybe a Action.Reset event.

Does anyone know if this is the case. Any possible workarounds to get the desired behavior?

Comment: If this is a POCO class, POCO means "Plain Old CLR Object" so it should only be doing what you have programmed it to do.  The idea behind POCO is that you're using your own classes rather than some "generated" proxy.  Is that not the case?

Comment: I believe "POCO proxy" is a commonly-used term describing Entity Framework 4's DynamicProxy subclasses of POCO entity classes, which is my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than likely it's something else; if at the base the property is a collection which implements INotifyCollectionChanged, nothing can stop anybody from subscribing to that event (it's not like routed events or anything). In my experience I never had problems with the proxy properties generated at runtime, at least. Look at how your collection is initialized and double-check your bindings, I'd say.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it isn't the bindings or a refresh issue. I will look more into it; maybe write some code to spit out a dll of the dynamic proxies so that I can run it through reflector.

Comment: Just to make sure - when adding the items, you do add them to the actual collection property, right? And not associate them through some other mechanism? Someone I know did something similar a while ago, and his collection property didn't update because there was no fix-up in place, but that was because of (poorly) customized t4 templates more than anything else.

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing a direct add. I looked at it in reflector. The overridden property always returns the base property, after having given a delegate a chance to initialize it. I don't see the implementation of the delegate, and it might be possible for it to do something sneaky, but you're right, it's more likely something else.

Comment: Ok, I feel silly! The binding in the item DataTemplate was to an uninitialized navigation property's property. ListBoxItems were being added, they just had nothing to display. I really need to start looking for the simplest answer first.